# Google service account's private key doesn't work on production

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-run

I'm trying to work with google storage

```
 const storage = new Storage({
      projectId: this.config.get('PROJECT_ID'),
      credentials: {
        type: 'service_account',
        private_key: this.config.get('PRIVATE_KEY'),
        client_email: this.config.get('CLIENT_EMAIL'),
        client_id: this.config.get('STORAGE_CLIENT_ID'),
      },
    });
```

this is how env. file look like

```
PROJECT_ID=###########
PRIVATE_KEY="-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n########################\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
CLIENT_EMAIL=###################.iam.gserviceaccount.com
STORAGE_MEDIA_BUCKET=###########
STORAGE_CLIENT_ID=###########
```

every variable work well except PRIVATE_KEY that doesn't work in production.
**I deploy my server to google cloud by using cloud run**
I 100% sure that PRIVATE_KEY in cloud run is the same as in development
[here is how I set environment variable on cloud run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVAz3.png)

I have tried to set private_key directly in the code which is work well in both development and production so I'm sure that problem is how I set  environment variable on cloud run. but I don't know what to do.

```
const storage = new Storage({
      projectId: this.config.get('PROJECT_ID'),
      credentials: {
        type: 'service_account',
        private_key: "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n########################\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"
        client_email: this.config.get('CLIENT_EMAIL'),
        client_id: this.config.get('STORAGE_CLIENT_ID'),
      },
    });
```

Comment: Base64 encode the private key before storing it as an environment variable. Then base64 decode when you need to use it. Tip: include `private_key_id`. The KID (RSA public certificate thumbprint) is used to find the public certificate to verify RSA signatures. You might not use that feature but include it anyways.

Comment: I cannot add private_key_id to Strogae config it throws me the error "  private_key_id  is not assignable to type 'CredentialBody | ExternalAccountClientOptions'. Which I have already add private_key_id  to CredentialBody

Comment: As John Hanley suggest, I have solved the problem by using btoa() and atob() method in JavaScript to  encode and decode string to Base64  . but before I pass PRIVATE_KEY variable to  btoa()   I need do delete  \n and enter it down instead so it works well